# Selecting Listitems with Drag not working

Tags: delphi, listview, mouse

On the `MouseMove` event I need to select items in the Listview if my mouse click is dragging over them. My code however is not working. When I click and drag only the first item I click gets selected.

In the `MouseMove` event:

```
//If left mouse button is depressed
if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) = 1) then
  begin
    LListItem := NestingResultsListView.GetItemAt(x,y);

    //If the item is not selected, select it.
    if not LListItem.Selected then
    begin
      LListItem.Selected := true;
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

TListView has a [MultiSelect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.MultiSelect) property, check that in the Object Inspector and then you can select multiple items with mouse dragging, you don't need to code it yourself.

Comment: +1 I rather expect that if only @ika would remove all his code and use a vanilla control, then multi-select by mouse drag would simply work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `GetAsyncKeyState` returns the 'down' state in most significant bit of the word, so you should write something like `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BUTTON) and $8000 <> 0`.

Second, using `GetAsyncKeyState` for mouse buttons is not a very good thing since it checks for physical buttons (and if a user is left-handed and remaps the buttons he will be confused as your code expects left mouse button to be pressed). A better way would be to remember pressed mouse buttons in `OnMouseDown` event and update/reset them in `OnMouseUp` event.

Comment: You mean `GetKeyState` rather than `GetAsyncKeyState`. Not that I think this is the way to do it, but if you were to call one of those functions in a mouse move event, it would be `GetKeyState`.

Comment: The OP uses `GetAsyncKeyState`, and I mean it also. And I didn't find in `GetKeyState` documentation that it supports mouse buttons, while it's explicitly stated for `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Comment: The OP might well use `GetAsyncKeyState`, but do you think it's the right thing to do? And yes, you can pass `VK_LBUTTON` to `GetKeyState`. I'd like to see you fix the answer.